How to make my stripe subscription code working with all this setup currently i have
Hey guys is there anyone who is familiar with tanstack form as well as stripe payments actually I am currently in a situation where i want to integrate stripe in my project but I am unable to do so also I am a newbie to backend and its tech you can say that this is my first project where I am actually interacting with backend can anyone here help me to integrate stripe in my project
src/routes/ProMember.jsx



import { createFileRoute, useNavigate } from "@tanstack/react-router"





export const Route = createFileRoute("/ProMember")({

component: ProMember,

});



function ProMember() {

const navigate = useNavigate();

const handleBuyClick = (plan) => {

 navigate({to:`/SubscriptionPage/${[[plan.id,plan.title]]}`});

 

};

const MembershipCardData = [

 {

   id: 1,

   title: 'BASIC',

   price: '99.00 $/month',

   Benefits: [{first: '✓ Extra tools', second:null,third:null, fourth:null}] ,

   Height: 'h-[310px]'

 },

 {

   id: 2,

   title: 'PRO',

   price: '149.00 $/6 months',

   Benefits: [{first: '✓ Extra tools',second:'✓ free Newsletter', third:null, fourth:null }],

   Height: 'h-[310px]'

 },

 {

   id: 3,

   title: 'ADVANCED',

   price: '599.00 $/year',

   Benefits: [{first: '✓ Extra tools', second:'✓ free Newsletter',third: '✓ Extra support', fourth: '✓ Custom Tools (T&C apply)' }],

   Height: 'h-[335px]'

 }

]

console.log(MembershipCardData[0].Benefits[0].first)

return (

 <>

   <div className='w-screen h-screen bg-white-900 flex justify-center flex-wrap overflow-auto'> 

     {MembershipCardData.map(data =>

   (  

   <div className={`bg-brand-secondary w-[300px] m-7 rounded-sm text-brand-primary p-2 shadow-card ${data.Height}`}  key={data.id}>

     <div className='p-0.5 text-3xl flex justify-center font-black'>

       {data.title}

     </div>

     <hr/>

     <div className = ' text-2xl pt-1.5 pb-2 mt-1 font-semibold'>{data.price}</div>

     <div className='bg-brand-primary rounded-xl text-brand-secondary p-2 mt-2 shadow-card'>

     <div className='text-xl font-medium border-b-2 border-brand-secondary w-20 h-7'>Benefits</div>

     <div className='m-1 ml-0'>

        <span>{data.Benefits[0].first}</span>

       <br/>

       <span>{data.Benefits[0].second}</span>

       <br/>

       <span>{data.Benefits[0].third}</span>

       <br/>

       <span>{data.Benefits[0].fourth}</span>

     </div>

       

   </div>

     <div className='w-70 flex justify-center'>

     <button className='bg-brand-quaternary h-10 w-20 font-bold text-2xl rounded-md m-5 shadow-button' onClick={() => handleBuyClick(data)}>Buy</button>

       </div>

   </div>

   ))}

   </div>

 </>

)

}



src/routes/Subscription Page/$SubscriptionPlan.jsx



import {Elements} from '@stripe/react-stripe-js'

import {loadStripe} from '@stripe/stripe-js'

import React, { useState } from "react";

import { createFileRoute,useNavigate } from "@tanstack/react-router";

import {SubscriptionForm} from '../../SubscriptionForm'





export const Route = createFileRoute("/SubscriptionPage/$SubscriptionPlan")({

 loader: ({ params }) => params.SubscriptionPlan,

component: SubscriptionPage,

});



const stripePromise = loadStripe("My publishable keys that i putted here in double quotes");



function SubscriptionPage() {





const navigate = useNavigate();

const { SubscriptionPlan } = Route.useParams()







return (

 <>

   <Elements stripe ={stripePromise}>

     <SubscriptionForm plan = {SubscriptionPlan} />

   </Elements>  

 </>

);

}

src/SubscriptionForm.jsx



import { CardElement, useStripe, useElements } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js'

import { useForm } from "@tanstack/react-form";

import { valibotValidator } from "@tanstack/valibot-form-adapter";

import { string, email, minLength } from "valibot";





export function SubscriptionForm({plan}) {





const stripe = useStripe();

const elements = useElements();

const planData = plan ;

const planId = planData.slice(0,1)

const planTitle = planData.slice(2)





 const form = useForm({

 defaultValues: {

   Name: "",

   Email: "",

   Card: "",

 },

 onSubmit: async ({value}) => { 

   try {

     const paymentMethod = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({

       type: 'card',

       card: elements.getElement("card"),

     });

     const response = await fetch('/create-payment-intent',{

       method: 'POST',

       headers: {

         'Content-Type': 'application/json',

       },

       body: JSON.stringify({ 

         planId: planId, 

         planTitle: planTitle, 

         Name:value.Name, 

         Email: value.Email }),

   });

     if(response.ok)return alert('Payment Unsucessful!')

     const data = await response.json();

    const confirm = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(data.clientSecret)

if(confirm.error) return alert('Payment Unsucessful!')

alert('Payment Successful! Subscription Active')    





   /*try{

     const response = await fetch("/create-payment-intent", {

     method: "POST",

     headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },

     body: JSON.stringify({ planId: planId, planTitle: planTitle, Name:value.Name, Email: value.Email }),

   });



   const data = await response.json();

   const clientSecret = data.clientSecret;



   const paymentResult = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {

     payment_method: {

       card: elements.getElement(CardElement),

     },

   });



   if (paymentResult.error) {

     console.error(paymentResult.error);

     alert("Payment failed!"+ paymentResult.error.message);

   } else {

     console.log("Payment successful!", paymentResult);

   }*/

   }catch(err){

     console.log(err);

     alert('payment failed,' + err.message);    

   }

 },

 validatorAdapter: valibotValidator,

});

return (

 <>

 <div className="h-screen w-screen bg-white-900 flex justify-center items-center">

       <div className="h-[360px] w-[280px] bg-brand-secondary text-brand-primary  shadow-card rounded-md flex flex-col items-center">

         <form

           onSubmit={(e) => {

             e.preventDefault();

             e.stopPropagation();

             void form.handleSubmit();

           }}

         >

           <span className="text-4xl font-bold text-brand-primary font-family-inter flex justify-center p-2">

             SUBSCRIBE

           </span>

           <div className=" h-[190px] w-[280px] flex flex-col items-center justify-around ">



             <form.Field

validators={{

                 onChange: string([

                   minLength(

                     3,

                     "Full                Name must be at                  least 3 characters",

                   ),

                 ]),

               }}

               name="Name"

             >

               {(field) => (

                 <>

                   <div className="flex flex-col justify-center">

                     <label className="text-xl">Name</label>

                     <input

                       type="Name"

                       className="mt-1 rounded-sm p-2  h-[35px] w-[240px] text-brand-secondary flex justify-center"

                       name={field.name}

                       value={field.state.value}

                       onBlur={field.handleBlur}

                       onChange={(e) => field.handleChange(e.target.value)}

                     />

                   </div>

                   {field.state.meta.errors ? (

                     <em

                       role="alert"

                       className="text-brand-teritary text-sm font-family-inter font-bold"

                     >

                       {field.state.meta.errors.join(", ")}

                     </em>

                   ) : null}

                 </>

               )}

             </form.Field>



             <form.Field

         validators={{

onChange: string([email('Enter a valid email address')]),

}}            

               name="Email"  

               

             >

               {(field) => (

                 <>

                   <div className="flex flex-col justify-center mt-3">

                     <label className="text-xl">Email</label>

                     <input

                       className="mt-1 rounded-sm p-2

h-[35px] w-[240px] text-brand-secondary flex justify-center"

                       name={field.name}

                       type="email"

                       value={field.state.value}

                       onBlur={field.handleBlur}

                       onChange={(e) => field.handleChange(e.target.value)}

                     />

                   </div>

                   {field.state.meta.errors ? (

                     <em

                       role="alert"

                       className="text-brand-teritary text-sm font-bold font-family-inter"

                     >

                       {field.state.meta.errors.join(", ")}

                     </em>

                   ) : null}

                 </>

               )}

             </form.Field>

<form.Field

         validators={{

onChange: string([email('Enter a valid email address')]),

}}            

               name="Email"  

               

             >

               {(field) => (

                 <>      

                   <div id='form-field' className="flex flex-col justify-center mt-3">

                     <label className="text-xl">Card Details</label>

                     <div className = 'bg-brand-primary text-brand-secondary h-[35px] w-[240px] rounded-sm p-2'>



             <CardElement/>

</div>

                   </div>

</>

               )}

             </form.Field>

           </div>

           <div className="flex justify-center mt-[60px]">

             <form.Subscribe

               selector={(state) => [state.canSubmit, state.isSubmitting]}

               children={([canSubmit, isSubmitting]) => (

                 <button

                   type="submit"

                   disabled={!canSubmit}

                   className="bg-brand-quaternary text-xl font-bold flex justify-center items-center rounded-md shadow-button p-2 "

                 >

                   {isSubmitting ? "..." : `SUBSCRIBE TO ${planTitle}`}

                 </button>

               )}

             />

           </div>

         </form>

       </div>

     </div>

 </>

)

}



src/Subscribe.js


import Stripe from 'stripe';

const express = require('express');

const stripe = new Stripe('stripe')("My secret key that i putted here in double quotes")



const app = express();



app.post('/create-payment-intent',async(req,res) => {

try{

 if(req.method !== 'POST') return res.status(400);

const {planId,planTitle,Email,Name,paymentMethod} = req.body;

 

 const customer = await stripe.customers.create({

   email: Email,

   name: Name,

   payment_method: paymentMethod,

   invoice_settings: {default_payment_method: paymentMethod},

 })



 const product = await stripe.products.create({

   name:`${planTitle} Plan`,

 })



 const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create({

   customer:customer.id,

   items: [

     {

       price_data: {

         currency:'INR',

         product: product.id,

         unit_amount: calculatePriceInCents(planId),

         recurring: {

           interval: 'month',

         },

       },

     },

   ],

   payment_settings: {

     payment_method_options: ['card'],

     save_default_payment_method:'on_subscription',

   },

   expand: ['latest_invoice.payment_intent'],

 }); 

 res.json({

   message: 'Subscription sucessfull',

   clientSecret: subscription.latest_invoice.payment_intent.client_secret,

   subscriptionId: subscription.id,

 })

}catch(err){

 console.log(err);

 res.status(500).send('payment failed,' + err.message);

}



});



function calculatePriceInCents(planId) {

const planPrices = {

 1: 9900, // Replace with actual prices in cents

 2: 14900,

 3: 59900,

};

return planPrices[planId] || 0; // Return 0 for unknown plans

}



/*

app.post("/create-payment-intent", async (req, res) => {

try {

 const { planId } = req.body;



 let product;

 try {

   product = await stripe.products.create({

     name: `Plan: ${planId}`, 

   });

 } catch (err) {

   if (err.code !== "resource_already_exists") {

     throw err; 

   }

   product = await stripe.products.retrieve(`plan-${planId}`); 

 }

 const price = await stripe.prices.create({

   product: product.id,

   unit_amount: calculatePriceInCents(planId), // Function to calculate price in cents

   currency: "usd", // Replace with your desired currency code

 });



 // (Optional) Dynamically create customer

 let customer;

 if (req.body.email) { // Create customer if email is provided

   customer = await stripe.customers.create({

     email: req.body.email,

   });

 }



 const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create
({



This is my whole code and i am finding it difficult to actually do things here also I am getting an error on submitting the subscription form with the subscribe button on the form
The error is
SyntaxError {}
message: "Unexpected end of JSON input"
stack: "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input↵ at Object.onSubmit (https://dfdfc0c8-b50e-4037-aa34-cea130730c3f-00-3eebp8qm9h0io.sisko.replit.dev/src/SubscriptionForm.tsx:55:37)↵ at async FormApi.handleSubmit (https://dfdfc0c8-b50e-4037-aa34-cea130730c3f-00-3eebp8qm9h0io.sisko.replit.dev/node_modules/.vite/deps/@tanstack_react-form.js?v=7284fdcd:490:9
)"
Also i don't only want to resolve the error but also want to actually create a working stripe subscription accordingly to my plans for each of my customer help
I have tried Ai tools and also tried some tutorials and tried to learn from the videos but failed I also tried to read some blogs but I don't found any that will match my query so please if anyone can it would be grateful
